Why "Module not found" after python installation in venv?
I'm using Python 3.6.8 on RHEL 8.6, and I'm new to venv.  I'm remote, and my environment is extremely restrictive I cannot change python, add/update modules, access the root account, etc.  Only the single instance of Python is installed on the VM.
Without creating a virtual environment, when I execute pip3 list, I get a long list of packages (includes request, werkzeug, etc).  If I execute python without the virtual environment, I can import all listed packages (as I would expect).
Once I create the venv and execute python, I get the dreaded "module not found" for the key packages from the pip list command.
I made my project directory, and in the directory I created the virtual environment (python3 -m venv -m .pvenv).  When I execute the virtual environment (source .pvenv/bin/activate) and python3, I cannot import the long list of packages including requests and werkzeug ("module not found").  In the venv, the pip3 list command shows the matching list of packages matching the primary python installation.
Experimenting, I found that if I create the venv with the --system-site-packages option, I can import all packages listed by the pip command, but this is not the behavior I would expect without that option.
Has anyone experienced anything similar, and how did you resolve it without the additional option?

A virtual environment is a completely fresh Python environment which by default does not contain any third-party packages. Generally the reason you create one is to have a completely isolated environment, so it makes sense that you can't import packages from the system installation (by default, without passing --system-site-packages).

On my company Windows 10 instance for development and my MAC, I don't see this issue.  I don't use the ``system-site-packages"  option and those packages are available for import in the venv instances I create.  Those are our default packages, but I'm not using many of them in my projects, so I was hoping to limit the project to only those I'm actually using in a particular venv.

How do you create the virtual environments on your windows / mac computers? On my windows and mac, creating a virtual environment without --system-site-packages behaves as expected and creates a "fresh install" environment, where builtin packages (such as itertools) are available, but user packages installed on the system python instance (e.g. numpy) are not pre-installed. What you're seeing on the RHEL VM is the expected behavior.

python3 and pip3 are almost certainly not programs provided by your virtual environment. Don't use those commands at all (or at least, only use python3 to create the virtual environment); use python and pip after activation (or use venv/bin/{python,pip} directly).

I'm creating the virtual environment in exactly the same way in each environment.  with the exception of "Scripts" vs "bin" in Windows.

Both pip and pip3 are in the venv path and are the same executable.  I verified in Windows the pip/pip3 command is the executable from the venv path once activated.
